# lftp root directory mirroring not working as expexted

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this line of code:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="root"
PASS="sjkndkfjnweif"
SERVER="192.168.1.1"
SOURCE="/var/www/a1/"
TARGET="/volume1/a1/"
LOG="/volume1/homes/admin/backup-a1.log"

lftp sftp://$USER:$PASS@$SERVER -e 'mirror -r '$SOURCE $TARGET'; bye'
```

Script is called execute.sh and is located in this folder:

```
/volume1/homes/admin/execute.sh
```

I need that variable target is backuping in this folder:

```
/volume1/a1
```

And my script screates subdirectory in witch this script is run for example:

```
/volume1/homes/admin/a1/
```

I need to create folder for backup in

/volume1/a1

I try to add

./volume1/a1/ and ~/volume1/a1 but it every time script is run it creates subdirectory in folder that script it is run.

How to fix this to be working as it should be?

Answer (score 1):

> mirror [OPTS] [source [target]]
>
> Mirror specified source directory to local target directory. If 
>   the  target  directory  ends    with  a  slash  (except the root), the
>   source base name is appended to target directory name.    Source
>   and/or target can be URLs pointing to directories.

So remove slash from `TARGET`first:

```
TARGET="/volume1/a1"
```

Then you have to specify target base directory: `--target-directory`

```
--target-directory=DIR
```

Your final command line:

```
lftp sftp://$USER:$PASS@$SERVER -e "mirror -r --target-directory=/ $SOURCE $TARGET"
```

Comment: I removet it and it creates same subdirectory in witch script is executed...so problem is the same...

Comment: Could you please write example where to write target directory? I im beginner in linux....

Comment: thanks for example line i copy paste and run it but it creates subdirectory in directory where this script is run...

Comment: @John Strange...let me check this